# Code optimization and alternative method to handle this

Tags: laravel, database, performance, optimization, eloquent

```
 public function store(StoreWorkerRequest $request){    
    $attributes = $request->validated();
    $worker = DB::transaction(function () use ($attributes) {
        $worker = Worker::create($attributes);
        $course = $worker->course()->create(['course_name' => $attributes['course_name']]);
        $media = $course->media()->create(["filename" => fileUpload($attributes['doc_file'], 'Course'),"filetype" => "pdf"]);
        $medical_data = $worker->medical_detail()->create(['expiry_date' => $attributes['expiry_date']]);
        $document = $worker->document()->create(['doc_name' => $attributes['doc_name']]);
        return $worker
    });
    return success(new WorkerResource($worker), __('Workers created successfully'));
```

}

```
 THis is my StoreWorkerRequest
 return [
        'first_name' => ['required', 'string'],
        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:workers,email'],
        'last_name' => ['required', 'string'],
        'phone_number' => ['nullable', 'numeric'],
        'hourly_rate' => ['required', 'numeric'],
        'birth_date' => ['required','date'],
        'doc_file' => ['sometimes','file','mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,doc,docx,pdf,csv,xlsx'],
        'course_file' => ['sometimes','file','mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,doc,docx,pdf,csv,xlsx'],
        'medical_file' => ['sometimes','file','mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,doc,docx,pdf,csv,xlsx'],
        'course_name' => ['sometimes','string'],
        'doc_name' => ['sometimes','string'],
        'medical_name' => ['sometimes','string'],
        'expiry_date' => ['sometimes','date'],
    ];
}
```

. I am working this way. It it a good practice? media is a has many polymorphic relationship with `course`, `medical_detail` and `document`. and worker has One relationship with `course`, `medical_detail` and `document`. The problem here I found was , It gives error if any one the attribute field is missing, and also if if course create fails, then media->course()-> will give error? What will be a better approach? and does this approach effect performance? Came here for code optimization

Comment: This code looks incomplete, as in, you are showing the return part, but not the top part. Also, I'm not sure why you put the return array in as you do.  Usually you should make a Request object, which in turn contains all the rules and messages. https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#creating-form-requests

Also, AFAIK, `DB::transaction` does not return a value from itself. `$worker` is probably empty/null. You can return a value inside the closure of `DB::transaction()` and then fetch it, but in your example you don't seem to do this.

Answer (score 0):

All seems right except one moment. Your transaction doesn't have return, so the result will be `null`. You should do like so:

```php
public function store(StoreWorkerRequest $request){    
    $attributes = $request->validated();
    $worker = DB::transaction(function () use ($attributes) {
        $worker = Worker::create($attributes);
        $course = $worker->course()->create(['course_name' => $attributes['course_name']]);
        $media = $course->media()->create(["filename" => fileUpload($attributes['doc_file'], 'Course'),"filetype" => "pdf"]);
        $medical_data = $worker->medical_detail()->create(['expiry_date' => $attributes['expiry_date']]);
        $document = $worker->document()->create(['doc_name' => $attributes['doc_name']]);

        return $worker;
    });
    return success(new WorkerResource($worker), __('Workers created successfully'));
}
```

Everything other is okay. Transactions are designed to throw an error when at least one query was unsuccessful.